# Hide / Show menu code not working after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback

I have a button on my web page that toggles the menu, After a postback the menu comes back despite me updating a hidden field value to store its state. Am I doing something wrong here? If there is a better way of doing it, let me know!

Markup:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnMenu" runat="server" Text="Hide Menu" UseSubmitBehavior="False"
                                        OnClientClick="return toggleMenu(this);" />
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlMenuToggle">
        //Main Menu
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSubMenuToggle">
        //Sub Menu
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfMenuState" runat="server" Value="true" />

<script>


//Toggles menu visibility
        function toggleMenu(menuButton) {

            var menuVisible = $('#<%=hfMenuState.ClientID%>').val() == 'true' ? true : false;

            $('#<%=pnlMenuToggle.ClientID%>').slideToggleWidth();
            $('#<%=pnlSubMenuToggle.ClientID%>').slideToggle('slow');

            //Update whether the menu is visible
            menuVisible = !menuVisible;

            //Update menu button text
            $(menuButton).val(menuVisible ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');

            $('#<%=hfMenuState.ClientID%>').val(menuVisible)

            return false;
        }
</script>
```

Code Behind:

(Page Load)

```
        bool menu = Convert.ToBoolean( hfMenuState.Value );

        pnlMenuToggle.Visible = menu;
        pnlSubMenuToggle.Visible = menu;
```

The javascripts updates the hidden field value but it looks like this is never posted back to the server.

What can I do to make sure the menu stays hidden after postbacks.

I have also tried putting the hidden field in an Update Panel with Update Mode set to Always

Comment: Could it be because of the post back. Ie. check for IsPostBack before doing anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Here is what I have come up with...

**Master Page:**

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnMenu" runat="server" Text="Hide Menu" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClientClick="return toggleMenu(this);" />
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlMenuToggle">
            //Main Menu
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSubMenuToggle">
            //Sub Menu
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfMenuVisible" runat="server" Value="true" />

     <script type="text/javascript">


    //Toggles menu visibility
            var _MenuVisible = $('#<%=hfMenuVisible.ClientID%>').val() == 'true' ? true : false;

            function toggleMenu(menuButton) {

                $('#<%=pnlMenuToggle.ClientID%>').slideToggleWidth();
                $('#<%=pnlSubMenuToggle.ClientID%>').slideToggle('slow');

                //Update whether the menu is visible
                _MenuVisible = !_MenuVisible;

                //Update menu button text
                $(menuButton).val(_MenuVisible ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');

                //Update menu visibility via ajax
                $.ajax(
                      {
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "Default.aspx/UpdateMenuVisibility",
                          data: "{ 'visible': '" + _MenuVisible + "' }",
                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                          dataType: "json"
                      });

                return false;
            }

</script>
```

Page Load:

```
 if ( Default.MenuVisible )
        {
            pnlMenuToggle.Style.Remove( "display" );
            pnlSubMenuToggle.Style.Remove( "display" );
            btnMenu.Text = "Hide Menu";
            hfMenuVisible.Value = true.ToString().ToLower();
        }
        else
        {
            pnlMenuToggle.Style.Add( "display", "none" );
            pnlSubMenuToggle.Style.Add( "display", "none" );
            btnMenu.Text = "Show Menu";
            hfMenuVisible.Value = false.ToString().ToLower();
        }
```

**Default.aspx:**

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets whether the Menu Is Visible
    /// </summary>
    public static bool MenuVisible
    {
        get
        {
            if ( HttpContext.Current.Session[ "MenuVisible" ] == null )
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[ "MenuVisible" ] = true;
            }

            return ( bool ) HttpContext.Current.Session[ "MenuVisible" ];
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[ "MenuVisible" ] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates whether the menu is visible or not
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="visible">visible</param>
    [WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
    public static void UpdateMenuVisibility( bool visible )
    {
        try
        {
            Default.MenuVisible = visible;
        }
        catch ( Exception )
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Basically, the hide show menu button now updates a session variable to track whether the menu is visible between post backs even if the master page is recreated.

This works a treat.

Comment: It helped me to find a solution for my application. I did some changes and it worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The button has `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` so it will never post to the server. That's why the value in the hidden field is not submitted.

Comment: Ah, You may have it there - I think I may also need to store menu state in the session as it will be reset whenever the page is recreated. I'm just trying that now..

Comment: ok, I have removed the use submit behaviour from the button but its still not working - I dont want the hide menu button to post back as its a quick client side menu toggle. However, When the page does postback the value of the hidden field is changed, its just forgotten by the time it gets to page load?

Comment: The value is changed when the page is loaded or when you click on the button?

Comment: got it working thanks, I came up with another solution using a session variable combined with ajax and a hidden value - I have added the answer :)